# Neighborhood of a point (real number)

Tags: real-analysis

How can we prove that every real number has **infinitely many neighbourhoods**?
I know that it is true because we can consider a symmetric epsilon neighborhood of a point and there are infinitely many number of such epsilons.
But how can we prove it rigorously?

Comment: What you wrote constitutes a rigorous proof unless the examiner demands formalism / symbolism (these properties are completely different from rigor).

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it rigorously by constructing an infinite set of neighborhoods for an arbitrary real number $x$, and, of course, showing that the set is indeed infinite.

Your idea, i.e. "consider a symmetric epsilon neighborhood of a point", is a very good start. Now try to actually construct a set of all such neighborhoods. To show that it is infinite, it is best find a bijection from that set to some other set which you know is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$.

The set $\{1/n: n \in \mathbb N\}$ is not finite. For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $I_n:=(x_0-1/n,x_0+1/n)$. Then

$$\{I_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$$

is an infinite set of neighbourhoods of $x_0$.